# Java Code Generation (JPA) from Oracle Data Modeler?

Tags: hibernate, svn, jpa, data-modeling

I am looking for FREE data modeling tool supporting SVN.

One of the tool is Oracle Data Modeler which does the job fine.My problem is that I need to generate Java class definition and Hibernate mapping files from the data model.

Is there any way to get Java code generated from Oracle Data Modeler? I want class definition/Hibernate mapping files for entities etc.

If not then is there any other way or a free data modeling tool which support SVN and JPA? code generation from existing database table is out of the question as we want SVN functionality (store different versions of the Data Model)

Comment: What did you do in the end?